# Secret Manager- To create the secret of a secret_name which is out there already and used by production application

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, gcp-secret-manager

We are trying to run terraform script to increase the size of Redis instance.
The plan says, it is going to create the secret of a secret_name which is out there already and used by production application.

Solution for the error

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Terraform import](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/import).
More specifically for a [secret manager secret](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/secret_manager_secret#import).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).